# Replace 0's with previous non-zero value per ID (lag)

Tags: r, replace, lag, zero

How can I replace all 0's with the last non-zero value per ID in R?

Example:

**Input:**

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
         Var1 = c(0,10, 30, 0, 0,50,80,0, 0, 57, 0))
```

**Output:**

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
         Var1 = c(0,10, 30, 0, 0,50,80,0, 0, 57, 0),
         res = c(0,10,30,30,30,50,80,0,0,57,57))
```

Is there an easy way with lag function?

Comment: `library(zoo);
na.locf(replace(df$Var1, df$Var1 == 0, NA))
`

Comment: @RonakShah I obtained a  short vector when the first value is 0:
    10 30 30 30 50 80 80 80 57 57
How can I omit this, and maintain the first 0 per id

Comment: @RonakShah Did you delete your answer with : library(zoo)
df$res <- c(df$Var1[1],na.locf(replace(df$Var1[-1], df$Var1[-1] == 0, NA))) ?

It was so helpful

Comment: Yes, I did because I did not considered the per `ID` thing. You can modify the answer by @docendo discimus `df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(x = na.locf(replace(Var1, cumsum(Var1 !=0) > 0 & Var1 == 0, NA)))` which should give you expected output.

Comment: where do you get these interesting problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(x = replace(Var1, cumsum(Var1 !=0) > 0 & Var1 == 0, NA)) %>% 
  fill(x)
# # A tibble: 11 x 4
# # Groups:   ID [2]
# ID  Var1   res     x
# <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    1.    0.    0.    0.
# 2    1.   10.   10.   10.
# 3    1.   30.   30.   30.
# 4    1.    0.   30.   30.
# 5    1.    0.   30.   30.
# 6    1.   50.   50.   50.
# 7    1.   80.   80.   80.
# 8    2.    0.    0.    0.
# 9    2.    0.    0.    0.
# 10    2.   57.   57.   57.
# 11    2.    0.   57.   57.
```

In the mutate step, we replace 0's with NA except for those that are at the beginning of each ID-run because in those cases we have no values to replace the NAs afterwards.

---

If you have multiple columns to adjust, you can use:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Var")), 
            funs(replace(., cumsum(. !=0) > 0 & . == 0, NA))) %>% 
  fill(starts_with("Var"))
```

where df could be:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                 Var1 = c(0,10, 30, 0, 0,50,80,0, 0, 57, 0),
                 Var2 = c(4,0, 30, 0, 0,50,0,16, 0, 57, 0))
```

Comment: You could also add the `na.locf` option in your answer.

Comment: @docendodiscimus that worked!

How can I adapt the code for a multi-column case? This is: many "Vars"

Answer (score 1):

Without using any package, just using the `loops`:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                 Var1 = c(0,10, 30, 0, 0,50,80,0, 0, 57, 0)) 

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(i!=1){    
    if(df$ID[i-1]==df$ID[i] && df$Var1[i]==0){  # if value is zero and value of current and previous rows ID are same
      if(df$Var1[i-1]!=0){           # If previous value is not zero then store it 
        df$res[i]=df$Var1[i-1]       # Use previous value of var1
        a=0
        a=df$Var1[i-1]
      }else{
        df$res[i]=a     # Use previous value var1
        a=0
      }
    }else{
      df$res[i]=df$Var1[i]  # Use the current value of var1
    }

  }else{
    df$res[i]=df$Var1[i]    # Set the first point as it is
  }
}
```

Output:

```
> df
      ID Var1 res
   1   1    0   0
   2   1   10  10
   3   1   30  30
   4   1    0  30
   5   1    0  30
   6   1   50  50
   7   1   80  80
   8   2    0   0
   9   2    0   0
   10  2   57  57
   11  2    0  57
```

Comment: @AM.Garcia: Could you please check the answer and allow me to know your suggestions?

Comment: tried under the test df and works. However my dataset is too big, and loops will probably delay the execution, thank you