# Tidyverse to Get the Last Numeric Value in a Dataframe Hangs

Tags: r

I have a scaled-down dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Name=c('A','A','B','B','B','B','A','A','A','B'),
                 Date=c('2018-04','2018-05','2018-06','2018-07','2018-08','2018-09','2018-10','2018-11','2018-12','2019-01'),
                 Value=c(4,1,2,NA,4,6,NA,8,3,5))
```

I'm trying to replace the NA with the last known numeric variable.  In the dataframe created, the first NA from the top should be replaced by 2, the 2nd NA replaced by 1.

I've tried tidyverse from this post: [Replace 0's with previous non-zero value per ID (lag)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50966647/replace-0s-with-previous-non-zero-value-per-id-lag)

And applied it like:

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(x = replace(Value,NA,0)) %>% fill(x)
```

Which replaces it as intended.  However, in the larger data, I'm not sure if my tidyverse code is correct as my R sort of hangs on the actual data after reaching 100%.

|========================================================== |100% ~0 s remaining

Hopefully someone could point me to the right direction on why it hangs or have an alternate solution (in case of hardware limitations) in getting the last numeric value of an ID(Name) if its latest value is NA.

Comment: The `mutate` and `replace` part is not doing anything, you don't need it. `df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  fill(Value)` is the same. See if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The recommended code works on the example dataframe,  
I've applied it at the actual data and it's currently at the 100% ~0s remaining phase again.  I'll leave it running and clock how long it will take.

Comment: shouldn't the second `NA` be replaced with 6?

Comment: depending on your computer, you may try to use multiple clusters with `multidplyr` and `multidplyr::partition` instead of `group_by`

Comment: For name 'B', The 2nd NA is at 2019-07, the immediate previous (sorted) month's value is 2 (2018-06)

Comment: will try multiple clusters when it still hangs.  Thank you!

Comment: To update all, the statement successfully terminated after a couple of hours(!!).  Doing a quick scan, it performed as expected and I was able to get the desired output.  I'll try to find alternate ways to make it go faster -the multiple clusters suggested is a good start.  Thank you all!